# Duplicate "Log in" button when logging in to Team

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, login

In a browser where I'm not logged in, when I navigate to e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/, and click the 'I **have** a Stack Overflow account' option, I see two login buttons:

[image]

Comment: Two factor authentication ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! That's a pretty blatant one that slipped through the cracks.

I've just pushed a fix so you no longer have to choose between *Log in* and *Log in* ;)